# netty retry connect client will freeze

Tags: java, networking, netty, nio

I try to create a client which will retry connect when previous connection timeout. This program tries to connect to localhost:8007  which port 8007 is without any service, so the program will retry after connection time out. But this code will free after running for a while. The program freezes when there are about 3600 threads. I expect it will continue to retry rather than it will freeze.

The standard output's last output is "retry connect begin".

Does anyone know the reason why it will freeze?

JProfiler: program's Thread statistic, shows 2 threads are blocked on java.lang.ThreadGroup:

[JProfiler showing program's Thread statistic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iesL.png)

```
public final class EchoClient2 {

    static final boolean SSL = System.getProperty("ssl") != null;
    static final String HOST = System.getProperty("host", "127.0.0.1");
    static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "8007"));
    static final int SIZE = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("size", "256"));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Configure SSL.git
        EchoClient2 echoClient2 = new EchoClient2();
        echoClient2.connect();
    }

    public void connect() throws InterruptedException {
        final SslContext sslCtx;

        // Configure the client.
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                            //p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
                            p.addLast(new EchoClientHandler());
                        }
                    });

            // Start the client.
            ChannelFuture f = b.connect(HOST, PORT);
            f.addListener(new ConnectionListener());
            System.out.println("add listener");
            f.sync();
            System.out.println("connect sync finish");

            // Wait until the connection is closed.
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
            System.out.println("channel close");
        } finally {
            // Shut down the event loop to terminate all threads.
            //group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}


public class ConnectionListener implements ChannelFutureListener {

    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("enter listener");

        EventLoop eventLoop = channelFuture.channel().eventLoop();

        eventLoop.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("retry connect begin");
                    new EchoClient2().connect();
                    System.out.println("retry connect exit");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        System.out.println("exit listener");
    }
}
```

Comment: `The program freezes when there are about 3600 threads` Not very surprising.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't block event loop which you did (by calling `f.sync();`)

Comment: do you know why it will freeze after for a while?